# Write a unit test to test a static method that returns it's own classes' constants

Tags: php, unit-testing, static-methods

I have been tasked with writing a unit test for class with a bunch of static methods, most of which return some sort of constant defined in the class itself, and was pondering about the value of a test which is merely asserting things from within the test itself. eg:

```
public static function stringToHex($color = null) {
    switch($color) {
        case 'green':
            return self::OK; // self::OK = '#00cc00'
        break;
        default 'red':
            return self::DANGER; // '#cc0000'
    }
}
```

How would I effectively test the return value when its defined in the class I'm testing itself? Off the top of my head it would be like this:

```
public function teststringToHex() {
    $this->assertEquals(MyClass::stringToHexColor('green'), MyClass::OK);
}
```

But this  doesn't seem right as I am asserting the outcome to be something the test doesn't even know the value of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right now your test trusts and depends on an implementation detail to be correct. Thats fine unless you dont trust that the constant has the right value. If so, you should pass in the hex values for the expectation, for instance with a DataProvider

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provideColorToHexMapping
 */
public function testStringToHex($colorName, $expectedHex) {
    $this->assertEquals(
        $expectedHex,
        MyClass::stringToHexColor($colorName)
    );
}
public function provideColorToHexMapping()
{
    return array(
        array('green', '#00cc00'),
        …
    );
}
```

Comment: @Dunhamzzz the dataprovider will pass it